# dplyr: how to include specific rows based on their position in filter function?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by

I would like to select a subsample of my data in R, according to the following condition:
t1(first row of group) - t1(i row of group) >= 2.

Dummy data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

t1 <- c(4,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,8,8,7,7,7,6,3)

df <- data.frame(id, t1)
```

Specifically, my intended output is:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
t1 <- c(2,2,2,1,1,6,3)
df2 <- data.frame(id, t1)
```

I am trying to find a solution using `dplyr`, `group_by()` and `filter()`, but I can't find a way to include the index of the first row of every group.
I tried :

```
df %>% group_by(id)%>% filter(lag(t1)-t1 >= 2)
```

But it's not what I want, maybe something using `row_number()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `lag`, but `first` should help you there

```
> df %>%
+   group_by(id) %>%
+   filter(first(t1) - t1 >= 2)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id    t1
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     1     2
3     1     2
4     1     1
5     1     1
6     2     6
7     2     3
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[first(t1) - t1 >= 2], id]
   id t1
1:  1  2
2:  1  2
3:  1  2
4:  1  1
5:  1  1
6:  2  6
7:  2  3
```

---

A base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
> subset(
+   df,
+   ave(t1, id, FUN = function(x) x[1]) - t1 >= 2
+ )
   id t1
4   1  2
5   1  2
6   1  2
7   1  1
8   1  1
14  2  6
15  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can also do

```
subset(df, (t1[!duplicated(id)][id] -t1) >= 2)
```

-output

```
#   id t1
#4   1  2
#5   1  2
#6   1  2
#7   1  1
#8   1  1
#14  2  6
#15  2  3
```